# Loopback Update model extend from User Model Error

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I have created an Artist model with User as its based model. I was trying to update the artist model through the Loopback explorer but i have an error:

> "message": "ValidationError: The `Artist` instance is not valid. Details: `password`
>   can't be blank (value: undefined); `email` can't be blank (value:
>   undefined)."

I have already registered a sample info and i have it in my artist db in MongoDB. i am not sure why i need to put something in the email and password field when i was only trying to update an existing data?

[image]

here is my artist JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Artist",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "middleName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "telephoneNumber": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "city": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "genre": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "pricing": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "profilePicture": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": [
        "updateAttributes",
        "deleteById"
      ]
    },
    {
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],

  "methods": {}
}
```

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your entity is inherited from a **User** model, it needs to have the '*password*' and '*email*' attributes set when using **POST** or **PUT** methods (so the **whole** object is created/updated) - as they are used to log the user in.

If you simply want to update your Artist whithout passing the whole datas, use **PATCH**. (Then '*password*' and '*email*' won't be mandatory anymore).

If you don't need to use the Loopback's login system, do not inherit your entity from the **User** model. (Or is there another reason for you to do so?)

Comment: Hi! Thank you! yes i need loopbacks login system as well as the Authorization so i inherited the User model.

Comment: Alright then, is using PATCH instead of PUT helped you?

Comment: Hi, yes it did!